C++ improving oop design in rendering engine
I'm working on a rendering engine as a hobby project and I've decided to do an OOP approach, but looking at my code I don't think I'm utilizing it the best, for example I've ran into an issue where I need to use casting which I don't think is ideal. I'd like to know how I could improve this or if the whole idea is just flawed.
The idea was to have a SceneElement base class which represents objects in the scene such as a Model, Camera, LightSource, etc and then my Sceneclass has a vector ofSceneElement` which the renderer (or other code) could loop through, although as I mentioned I learned I need to do casting to get the right type and having a single container doesn't seem as smart as I thought.
class Scene {
public:
    Scene() {}
    ~Scene() {}
    void loadScene() {}
    void addElement(ElementType type)
private:
    std::vector<SceneElement> elements
};

class SceneElement {
public:
    SceneElement() {}
    virtual ~SceneElement() {}
protected:
    Name name;
    Transform transform;
};

class Model : public SceneElement {};
class Camera : public SceneElement {};
class AudioSource : public SceneElement {};

void renderScene(const Scene& scene) {
    for (auto& element : scene.elements) {
        // dynamic_cast to make sure element is a model
    }
}


You misuse OOP. Check out some videos, say on data-oriented design from CPPCON: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yy8jQgmhbAU

Welcome to the Code Review community. On this site we review real code from a working project to help you improve your coding skills. As part of a code review  some of us may review design, but design by itself is off-topic on this site. There is a site that can help you, Please read Where can I get help? and How do I ask a good question?.

Polymorphism
In polymorphism, virtual functions are the way to go. Actions of the derived class are changed by adding virtual functions to the base class.
A well-known example of polymorphism is Shape class:
class Shape {
  virtual void draw() const = 0;
};

When inheriting Shape class programmer can choose the definition of draw for different classes. Examples of derived classes could be Circle, Triangle, and Rectangle.
There are still use cases for dynamic_cast. For example, when adding a new function to the base class doesn't make sense. In your case what would be the default implementation of rendering SceneElement? Function render would make sense for Model but not for SceneElement.
That could also hint that maybe they shouldn't share a base class.
Inheritance
With inheritance, the programmer doesn't have to redefine information. It doesn't only save time but updating the base class will also update derived classes. It makes changes more automatic as new functions and bug fixes are written only once.
You have correctly used virtual destructor virtual ~SceneElement() {}. With a virtual destructor,  objects are released using a derived class destructor. Without virtual destructor, only base class destructor is used. That would leave all derived class members without destructing. Another option is to use a private destructor in the base class.
Protected access could be used for member functions when two different interfaces are needed, one for general users and one for derived classes. Here is an example:
class Foo {
public:
  void bar() { check(); bar(); }
protected:
  void do_bar() { /* do something */ }
};

When derived classes know that checking is not needed they can just call the function.
Usually base classes try to avoid having member variables. If they have member variables they probably should be private. In that way, the base class can keep invariants within the member variables.
In your case, I don't think that every derived class needs a name and a transform.
Vector
std::vector owns its values. When the value is added std::vector moves ownership of the value to the vector or creates a copy of the value and adds that copy to the vector. That is the reason why base classes cannot be used as such in a vector:
Derived derived;
std::vector<Base> vector;
vector.push_back(derived); // Creates new object of class Base

This is called object slicing because all derived members are sliced away.
For that reason, std::vector<SceneElement> elements should be changed to for example std::vector<SceneElement*> elements. Instead of pointers one should prefer smart pointers though. Smart pointers remove changes for memory leaks or access to deleted elements. Just remember that after std::move(pointer) you cannot access the old variable pointer anymore.
Revised implementation
Here is my main.cpp file containing different implementation of the same scenario. I tried to use as few lines as I could so it would be easier to read the big picture. I also added to the start an example with Shape class:
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <memory>


class Shape {
  public:
    virtual ~Shape() = default;
    virtual void draw() const = 0;
    virtual void rotate() = 0;
};

class Circle : public Shape {
  public:
    void draw() const { std::cout << "o\n"; }
    void rotate() { /* rotating a circle is simple */ }
};

class Triangle : public Shape {
  public:
    enum Rotation { north, east, south, west };

    friend Rotation& operator++(Rotation& rotation) {
      return rotation = static_cast<Rotation>((rotation+1) % 4);
    }

    void draw() const {
      if (rotation == north) std::cout << "A\n";
      if (rotation == east) std::cout << "|>\n";
      if (rotation == south) std::cout << "V\n";
      if (rotation == west) std::cout << "<|\n";
    }
    void rotate() { ++rotation; }

  private:
    Rotation rotation = north;
};


class Element {
  public:
    virtual void render() { /* Do nothing */ }
};

class Model : public Element {
  void render() override { std::cout << "render model\n"; }
};
class Camera : public Element {};
class Audio : public Element {};

class Scene {
  public:
    Scene() {
      auto m1 = std::make_unique<Model>();
      auto m2 = std::make_unique<Model>();
      auto camera = std::make_unique<Camera>();
      auto audio = std::make_unique<Audio>();

      elements.push_back(std::move(m1));
      elements.push_back(std::move(m2));
      elements.push_back(std::move(camera));
      elements.push_back(std::move(audio));
    }

    void render() {
      std::cout << "scene:\n";
      for (const std::unique_ptr<Element>& element : elements) {
        element->render();
      }
      std::cout << '\n';
    }

  private:
    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Element>> elements;
};


int main() {
  Scene scene;
  scene.render();

  auto c1 = std::make_unique<Circle>();
  auto c2 = std::make_unique<Circle>();
  auto t1 = std::make_unique<Triangle>();
  auto t2 = std::make_unique<Triangle>();

  c2->rotate();
  t1->rotate();

  std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Shape>> shapes;
  shapes.push_back(std::move(c1));
  shapes.push_back(std::move(c2));
  shapes.push_back(std::move(t1));
  shapes.push_back(std::move(t2));

  std::cout << "shapes:\n";
  for (const auto& shape: shapes) {
    shape->draw();
  }
}

Useful links
Here is a good Tutorial for C++. There are some chapters about virtual functions. Here is some guidelines for C++ programming.
